# How to reset Calendar Extender for Ajax Control Toolkit to its default value which should be empty string (server side)?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

How to reset Calendar Extender for Ajax Control Toolkit to its default value which should be empty string?
Reset to be server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reset both calendar extender and its target control (textbox).

```
        txtProductionDate.Text = string.Empty;
        calExtProductionDate.SelectedDate = null;
```